# Regex - recognise clusters of numbers and characters but only match a part with numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex that extracts numbers that might be related to age. It should recognise both simple 'forms' as 98, 1, 25 and more complex like 90-years-old. However, in case of more complex forms, I would like it to only match a number. I will later check if it concerns the age, but this is irrelevant for this question. What I have now, matches both numbers and character-parts:

```
\b(1[0-4]\d?|\d{0,2}\d{1})(-?years?)?\b
```

For example, in the string: `"18year old 23 year old 99 years old but not 25-year-old and 91year old cousin is 99 now and 90-year-old or 102 year old 505 0 year 1 year 11 year old 11 year 199 102 0-year13 13 14 22 33 45 8  99years"`, it matches 23, 99 etc. but 18year or 90-year is a single match with two groups.

How can I change it so that only a number in such a cluster is matched (a single group)?

Comment: I do not understand your question. The first part of the alternation matches the string representations of integers `10-14` and `100-149`, but you say you wish to match `'1'` and `'25'`, which are neither matched by the second part of the alternation. It would be more clear if you made no reference to ages and simply gave rules for identifying strings of digits you wish to extract.

Comment: I don't know why an answer was even attempted here. It is _not possible_, in fact it is _impossible_ to match / parse Language with Regular expressions ! Try a NLP4J module.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The rule is to find a number from the range [0,150]. According to regexr, it matches both 1 and 25, however the problem with 25 in this case is: it also matches the "-year" part.

Comment: @sln The answer below (from Wiktor Stribiżew) shows that it is possible. I mean, it matches only '25' in '25-years'.

Comment: @RobertSzooba - So regex can parse and extract `years` with meaning to get a span of time relating to it ? Really ? Searches for `regex for age recognition` will land here thinking they reached nirvana but it is false. You've just said `Natural Language Processing is a form of AI technology that allows computers to understand, process, and produce natural language (how humans interact with each other). NLP can be used to extract information from unstructured data for speech recognition, sentiment analysis, knowledge extraction, and much more!` is irrelevant then.

Comment: Nobody will ever think your regex solution is acceptable for NLP. _Years_ is just a 5 letter character sequence that is meaningless and is just free form unstructured text.  You should delete your post since internet search engines will pick up on your implication that you've found a NLP solution using regex. Given that search engines are also NLP themselves, you provide nothing but a false line item result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(\d{1,3})(?=-?year|\b)
\b\d{1,3}(?=-?year|\b)
```

The second one has no capturing groups. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLSsVD/2).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `(?=-?year|\b)` - a position immediately followed with an optional `-`, `year` or a word boundary.

Comment: Should someone ever need this, the final answer is: `\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-4]{2})(?=-?year|\b)`